# While using smbFileOutputStream it giving following error

Tags: java, jar, smb

java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: org/bouncycastle/asn1/asn1bitstring

At

SmbFileOutputStream File1 = new SmbFileOutputStream(File2);

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might want to read [ask] and add more details or risk your question to be closed without any answers. Further reading: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/, https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/, https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: Hi Jayesh, this is insufficient info to assist with your issue - please edit your question - please include code if your problem is with code you've written.